# Pause terminal between input lines

Tags: tcl, stdin, onpause

I'm looking for a way to mark a pause between each entry to let the script checks each entry before going further.

example, I have this simple code :

```
for {set i 0} {$i<5} {incr i} {
  set x [gets stdin]
  if {[string is integer -strict $x]} {
      puts "It's OK"
  } else {
      puts "It's not OK"
  }
}
```

with this code, if I put manually the entries one by one, the script has the time to check each entry, here is the output :

```
5
It's OK
dd
It's not OK
kk
It's not OK
55
It's OK
99
It's OK
```

but now if I do a copy/paste of :

```
5
dd
kk
55
99
```

here is now the output :

```
5
dd
kk
55
99
It's OK
It's not OK
It's not OK
It's OK
It's OK
```

Is there a way to give enough time after each entry to let the script the time to check before going to the next entry ?

Thank you.

Comment: So you want a pause when you paste? Paste where? Command line (windows/linux)? tkcon?

Comment: It's under Linux in command line, I'm looking for a way to give enough time to the script to check each entry when I do a copy/paste of all entries at once as input of this script.

Comment: In this case, the solution probably involves `exec stty raw`, reading the input char by char, and echo it back. I'll write an example later.

Comment: Not clear on what you're trying to do, but if you just want some literal pauses, use `after`.

Answer (score 1):

This is surprisingly hard to do. Here's why: the output of the pasted text is actually handled by the OS (it's part of the terminal emulation) before it gets into Tcl at all. While there are some things you can do (typically by calling `exec /bin/stty` with the right options), they don't help really all that much. For example, you can turn off echoing of the values and process all the keystrokes exactly as done (that's the `-echo` and `raw` options) but that leaves you having to do a lot of work to pretend that things are still in cooked mode (`-raw`) as that's what provides normal terminal input. *It's a **lot** of work.*

Theoretically, a library like readline would help: they already do the evil stty hacking for you. Except that in your *specific* case, they won't help as the strict interleaving model you want isn't one that is a common-enough requirement.

What I'd actually do in your position is rewrite the output so that it says what input is being checked each time, as well as the result (“`"5" is OK`”) as then I could take the values to parse from a file and still end up able to figure out what's going on without lots of fuss.

Answer (score 0):

Either add a `puts $x` in there, or change the messages:

```
for {set i 0} {$i<5} {incr i} {
  set x [gets stdin]
  set ok [string is integer -strict $x]
  puts [format {%s %s OK} $x [expr {$ok ? "is" : "is not"}]]
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I've just tried your script and the result is the same than my previous script. The script doesn't have time to respond to each entry at a time and all the responses are put at the end.

Comment: This is a function of how your terminal reacts to pasted text. It has nothing to do with Tcl at all. If you're concerned, feed your program in a different way: `printf "%s\n" 5 dd kk 55 99 | your_program.tcl`